# Convert string to integer- what should I return if string is invalid

Tags: java, string, coding-style

If I want to write a function that takes a string and converts it into an integer and I don't trust my input at all, what should I return if the string is invalid. I want to return 0 but would that be confusing since the number might actually be 0? Assume this is for an interview question and you need to check all edge cases.

Comment: A) That already exists in the core language (`Integer.parseInt()`) B) It throws an exception when the input is wrong.

Comment: why don't just use `Integer.parseInt();`

Comment: @Jigar Joshi: It's just a sample interview question I saw and wanted to know the best thing to return (and maybe what edge cases to check for)

Comment: There *are* no "edge cases". Either it's a textual representation of an integer ... or it's not.

Comment: @BrianRoach There is one edge case I can think of though, when the input exceeds the range for integer.

Comment: @Ankit - Then it's not, by definition, an `Integer` (and, the library function that already exists would throw the exception). What I mean is that there's no edge case in terms of what it returns; it's a binary scale. There's not a "It's sort of an int" case.

Comment: @BrianRoach kk got what you mean! :)

Answer (score 2):

In Java, it would be conventional to throw an Exception.  This is what `Integer.parseInt()` does, which is the official Java implementation of this functionality.

Comment: What about if it's null or the empty string? Should the empty string also throw an exception? Should the null string throw a different exception (i.e. nullpointerexception instead)?

Comment: Yes, and possibly, although `IllegalArgumentException` would be ok as well.

Answer (score 0):

> what should I return if the string is invalid

`Throw a RunTimeException`. **API** already does that for you.If your try to parse an invalid string using `Integer.parseInt(str)` it  would throw `NumberFormatException` at run time.

Comment: Last I checked, it was a NumberFormatException. I might be wrong though.

Comment: @AshwinMukhija oops, what was i thinkin.. been workin on date formtting lately. so kindagot used to parseException .. :P

Comment: If it's null or the empty string, should this also be considered a NumberFormatException?

Comment: @user1136342 yepp. as its documented in Integer.parseInt(). if the string doesn;t represent a valid int value it should throw NFE. :)

Answer (score 0):

One possible option is to return default value if string can't be converted to integer. For example:

```
public int convert(String input, int defaultValue) {
    try {
        return Integer.parseInt(input);    
    } catch (Exception e) {
        return defaultValue;            
    }
}
```